# jQuery scale div contents (nested div)

Tags: jquery, html, nested, scale, absolute

How can I get the blue box to scale with the red one? (using jQuery-UI)

http://jsfiddle.net/Y54EB/1/

This is the basic code, CSS:

```css
#outer {
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:1;
    background:#F00;
}
#nested {
    position:absolute;
    left:50px; top:20px;
    width:50px; height:20px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#00F;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="nested" onclick="$('#outer').effect('scale', {scale:'content',percent:50}, 1000);" />
</div>
```

Comment: im not sure you mean scale both ... i think you want the position to change too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is old, but if I understand you correctly, I was trying to achieve the same thing and came across this jQuery plugin that does the job:

https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki

Comment: This is absolutely my favorite answer ;-) Designing using percentages doesn't seem like a good idea for me, as I need things where they should be positioned and I can't spend time calculating things like 42.748%. This transform stuff does it all as you would scale things in a design app (in a row). Nice!

Answer (score 5):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/Y54EB/4/

The solution is basically to specify the dimensions and position of the nested div in % w.r.t. parent than in pixels.

Comment: OMG! It's a nice solution, but I have many different elements inside the div, it would be a nigthmare calculating all the percents. So, it isn't possible for jQuery to scale nested-fixed-position elements?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But if you need the nested elements to resize as the parent animates (i.e. childrens' size & position animating with parent's) to a smaller/bigger size, you'll need to use a CSS based solution. If its ok to size the children after the parent is done animating, then you can go for a jquery based solution.

Comment: I want everything being scaled at the same time, as a block, in despite of if it's position is px or %. In fact, I'm a long time flash developer struggling my brain with js + css ;-) BTW, I'm now making my elements independent (instead of being children of a parent div) and animating each one separately, which seems more consistent...

Answer (score 2):

Change your CSS to use percentages instead :

```
#nested {
    position:absolute;
    left:30%; top:20%;
    width:50%; height:20%;
    z-index:2;
    background:#00F;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

This way the `#nested` div is always in proportion to the `outer` div - also keeps its positioning

Working example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/Y54EB/5/

Answer (score 1):

jquery:

```
$('#outer, #nested').effect('scale', {scale:'content',percent:50}, 1000);
```

if you want also to reposition the nested blue box, dont use fixed Pixel positioning in CSS... use %

Comment: .effect() uses jquery-ui, not just jquery (as the first line of this answer states). Just wanted to give everyone a heads up =)